# boost::numeric::ublas::vector internal data storage pointer

Tags: c++, boost, cuda, c++11, ublas

I am using `boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double>` (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/vector.htm).

How can I get an internal data pointer to the double?
I need the internal pointer because I want to copy the vector to `CUDA (i.e. using cudaMemcpy)`.  Or is there any elegant way to copy my boost vectors/matrices across?

I know I can do something like:

```
boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double> vector;
double* ptr = &vector[0];
```

but is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you instantiate your vector using an `unbounded_array` as the storage model:

```
vector<double, unbounded_array<double,n_elements>> vector;
```

then you can do something like this:

```
cudaMemcpy(device_dest, 
           vector.data().begin(), 
           vector.data().size(), 
           cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

This works because the `unbounded_array` iterator is a standard C++ pointer to the type being stored.